# How to remove unchecked checkbox from React state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onchange

With a checkbox onChange event, how do I remove value from state array when unchecked in react?

State array:

```
this.state = { value: [] }
```

onChange function:

```
handleChange = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.setState({
            value: [...this.state.value, event.target.value]
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            value: [this.state.value.filter(element => element !== event.target.value)]
        });
    }
};
```

Not sure exactly what the .filter() should be doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're **very** close, except:

1. You need to remove the `[]` around your call to `filter`. `filter` returns an array. If you wrap that in `[]`, you're putting the array inside another array, which you don't want (in this case).

   and
2. Since you're updating state based on existing state, it's important to use the callback version of `setState`, not the version that directly accepts an object. State updates can be batched together, so you need to be sure you're dealing with the most recent version of the array.

So:

```
handleChange = ({target: {checked, value: checkValue}}) => {
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                 ^− destructuring to take the properties from the event,
//                    since the event object will get reused and we're doing
//                    something asynchronous below
    if (checked) {
        this.setState(({value}) => ({value: [...value, checkValue]}));
    } else {
        this.setState(({value}) => ({value: value.filter(e => e !== checkValue)}));
        //                                  ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−− No [] around  this
    }
};
```

There are some situations where you'd get away with using `this.state.value` instead of using the callback (for instance, if you **only** update `value` in response to certain events), but you have to be sure you know which ones they are; it's simpler just to use the callback.

---

FWIW, since it has multiple values in it, if it were me I'd call the state property `values` (plural) rather than `value`, which would also mean we didn't have to rename the `value` from the event target in the destructuring above:

```
handleChange = ({target: {checked, value}}) => {
    if (checked) {
        this.setState(({values}) => ({values: [...values, value]}));
    } else {
        this.setState(({values}) => ({values: values.filter(e => e !== value)}));
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey @T.J. Crowder, thanks for the answer :)
You reckon the element !== event.target.value is ok too?

Comment: @js-learner - Yes, since you're directly storing the values of the checkboxes, so you're comparing like for like. Note the update, there's a second thing you probably want to do above.

Comment: Ahh fantastic, and totally makes sense, thank you so much :)

Comment: `this.setState(({values}) => ({values: checked ? [...values, value] : values.filter(e => e !== value)}));`

Comment: Thanks @DennisVash for the typo fix edit! And yes, we could use the conditional. For me at that point we cross a complexity line, but that line is in different places for different people... :-)

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks for that too, a good way to do it too!

Comment: @DennisVash - It's `value` in the OP's original, which is what the first code block relates to; only `values` in the last code block suggesting changing the name of the state property.